# No root zip works on galaxy ace s5830

Tags: rooting, samsung

Yes, my phones old but it does me fine. The only prob really is the phones internal storage. I would like to delete loads of bloatware and be able to move stuff completely to the SD card. I am no idiot. I have tried numerous root zip files, followed the methods but never works.

My phone is running android 2.3.6 gingerbread BVKT4. I read somewhere that the latest update to BVKT4 blocks rooting. Is there anyway to get around this. Much thanks in advance to anyone that can help.

Comment: With such an old phone, and modern rooting method, including one-click apps, would most probably work. Stock recovery will prevent flashing zips of course, and that's why you need a custom recovery.

Comment: *"**any** modern rooting method". Sorry - can't edit previous comment now.

Comment: hi andy.by stock recovery,do u mean when u boot the phone after installing the zip.ie a custom recovery is another file that needs to be installed to boot the phone from? where do u find those i wonder?

Answer (score 0):

Look around [XDA-Developers](http://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-ace) for relevant resource. For a phone of this age and (past) popularity, not only root is readily available, you can also get custom ROMs up to KitKat (not necessarily stable).

One of the possible ways: flash a stock-ROM-compatible custom recovery, then flash SuperUser/SuperSU zip in there. If that's all you need then [this thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2609021) seems to be an alright starting point.

As always told, make a backup in the recovery for safety.

Comment: thanks andy i will have another go.i did try xda at one point, but only used the root zip on its own.